# Flutter: Widget is not a subtype of type 'ObstructingPreferredSizeWidget'

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to store my AppBar in a variable for using multiple places

My main.dart file contains -

```
final PreferredSizeWidget appBar = NavigationAppBar(_actionCall)
```

And navigation_app_bar contains -

```
class NavigationAppBar extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
  final Function actionCall;

  NavigationAppBar(this.actionCall);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Platform.isIOS ? 
    CupertinoNavigationBar(
      middle: Text(
        'ABC'
      ),
      trailing: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              child: Icon(CupertinoIcons.add),
              onTap: () => actionCall,
            )
        ],
      ),
    ) : 
    AppBar(
      title: Text('ABC'),
      centerTitle: false,
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () => actionCall,
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}
```

But when trying to run my flutter app getting following error.

```
type 'NavigationAppBar' is not a subtype of type 'ObstructingPreferredSizeWidget'
```

How can i solve this issue? Any kind help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to replace NavigationAppBar with PreferredSizeWidget in all applicable places in the code? This helped me.

There was a small difference in my problem because I had to replace AppBar (not NavigationAppBar) with PreferredSizeWidget.

This is probably related to some changes in the latest Flutter versions.